# Eclipse is using Gingerbread style Form Widgets, Text Fields etc. instead of JellyBean style

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated my Android SDK to API 18 (Android 4.3) and now the form widget and text field styles have reverted to old Gingerbread style.  How can I change this back?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the API level in the Graphical layout view

[image]